# jQuery: Find next Element with same class

Tags: jquery, html

I want the next Element with the same class. So I have a click action on the class
"calculationContainer". When I click this element, I want to have access of the next element with the class "calculationContainer". But all I tried doesn't work. Maybe someone can help me with this?

I have this HTML Code:

```
<div class="body">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="calculationContainer">
            <div class="element">
                <input type="text" id="name1">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="body">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="calculationContainer">
            <div class="element">
                <input type="text" id="name2">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="body">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="calculationContainer">
            <div class="element">
                <input type="text" id="name3">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my jQuery:

```
$('.calculationContainer').on('click', function() {
        var amountCalculationContainer = $(this);
        var nextAmountCalculationContainer = amountCalculationContainer.next('.calculationContainer');  //<- Only finds the div with class "element"

});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try This :-

```
$('.calculationContainer').on('click', function() {
    var $elem = $(this).closest('div.body').next().find('div.calculationContainer')    
});
```

Use `.closest()` to traverse up and find first `div.body` parent and then use `.next()` to get next element and then find `div.calculationContainer` with `.find()`.

Handle the situation when `.calculationContainer` is at last position(as shown in demo).

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/n0cfdxup/63/)

Comment: I get back an empty object in this case

Comment: @Zwen2012..check demo.

Answer (score 8):

A technique that won't break if you change the structure of the HTML is to:

1. Use [.index()](https://api.jquery.com/index/) to find the container in a list of all the containers
2. Increment the index
3. Call [.eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) to select the next container regardless of where it is in the DOM

**JavaScript:**

```js
const next = (event) => {
   const list =   $('.calculationContainer');   //all containers
   const index =  list.index($(event.target));  //current container
   const target = (index + 1) % list.length;    //increment with wrap
   const nextAmountCalculationContainer = list.eq(target);
   };
$('.calculationContainer').click(next);
```

See if you can catch the **red** button:
https://jsfiddle.net/55pmmzd6/68
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Perfect. This finds the next element with the same class as current and also omits all without class in question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.calculationContainer').on('click', function() {
    var next_ele = $(this).parents("body").find(".calculationContainer");
    var $next = next_ele.filter(":gt(" + next_ele.index(this) + ")").first()
    console.log($next.html())
  });
```

Comment: Sorry, but it finds the input field, don't know why

Comment: ok so you want - <div class="calculationContainer">
<div class="element">
<input id="name2" type="text">
</div>
</div> like this?

Comment: I think it would work when I use the correct class :-) Thanks for your help!!